# how to execute commands stored in various bash arrays, based on input array name from command line

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm using bash script. I'm trying to execute commands stored in different arrays, based on the input of the array name and the range/index of the array.  For example, I have a script commands.sh below and I'd like to execute the command like:

./commands.sh b 1 3

I like the output would display:

```
cmd_b1
cmd_b2
cmd_b3
```

Ultimately, I like to execute those commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=$1
begin=$2
end=$3

declare -a $array

a[0]="cmd_a0"
a[1]="cmd_a1"
a[2]="cmd_a2"

b[0]="cmd_b0"
b[1]="cmd_b1"
b[2]="cmd_b2"
b[3]="cmd_b3"

for (( i=$begin; i<=$end; i++ ))
do
    cmd=${array}[$i]
    echo "$cmd"
done

exit 0
```

I ran the script, but the output I got was:

```
b[1]
b[2]
b[3]
```

which aren't what I like to see.   Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Aside from the incorrect syntax `${array}[$i]` (array indexing would be `${array[$i]}`, your array named `array` was initialized to a scalar first, and later re-declared as array. Therefore it contains only one element.  You could get at this element by `${array[0]}`. Another oddity is that your code defines arrays named `a` and `b`, but never actually uses them. Honestly I have no clue what this script is **supposed** to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a variable name as the first argument, you can say:

```
declare -n ref=$1
```

then would you try:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -n array=$1
begin=$2
end=$3

declare -a a=("cmd_a0" "cmd_a1" "cmd_a2")
declare -a b=("cmd_b0" "cmd_b1" "cmd_b2" "cmd_b3")

for (( i=begin; i<=end; i++ ))
do
    cmd=${array[$i]}
    echo "$cmd"
done
```

Output for `./commands.sh b 1 3`

```
cmd_b1
cmd_b2
cmd_b3
```

Output for `./commands.sh a 0 2`

```
cmd_a0
cmd_a1
cmd_a2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I forgot to mention that actual commands I have are very long and they already stored in the form as I posted, line by line like that.  It's very hard to re-arrange them into form declare -a a=("cmd_a0" "cmd_a1" "cmd_a2").  Moreover, sometimes I need to execute command "cmd_dbd" of array a[] that I don't know what index it has, just an example.  I simplified the problem to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I think I still can make your solution works.  I can just split the declare -a a=( ) line into multiple lines.

Comment: My modification of the array assignments is trivial just to shorten the code. If you want to assign the arrays one by one, it is absolutely okay and it's up to you. BR.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -n array=$1
begin=$2
end=$3

a[0]="cmd_a0"
a[1]="cmd_a1"
a[2]="cmd_a2"

b[0]="cmd_b0"
b[1]="cmd_b1"
b[2]="cmd_b2"
b[3]="cmd_b3"

for (( i=begin; i<=end; i++ ))
do
    cmd=${array[$i]}
    echo "$cmd"
done

exit 0
```

- use `declare -n` to make `array` a reference to its value
- delete the no-longer needed `declare -a`
- fix the dereferencing: `[...]` must appear inside `${...}`, not after it
- remove unneeded `$` inside `((...))`

---

It will be safer to make each array element be the name of a function, rather than attempting to store complex command-lines in the strings. For example:

```
a[0]="cmd_a0"

#...

cmd_a0(){
    # actual command here (which can access $1,$2,etc)
}
```

Comment: Yes, your solution simply worked!! Fantastic, I don't need to re-arrange my arrays.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the (a,b) arrays in one associative array

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=$1
begin=$2
end=$3

declare -A cmds=(
        [a0]=cmd_a0
        [a1]=cmd_a1
        [a2]=cmd_a2
        [b0]=cmd_b0
        [b1]=cmd_b1
        [b2]=cmd_b2
        [b3]=cmd_b3
)

for (( i=begin; i<=end; i++ ))
do
    cmd=${cmds[${prefix}${i}]}
    echo "$cmd"
done
```

---

```
./commands.sh b 0 3
cmd_b0
cmd_b1
cmd_b2
cmd_b3

$ ./commands.sh a 0 1
cmd_a0
cmd_a1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

array=$1
begin=$2
end=$3

a[0]="cmd_a0"
a[1]="cmd_a1"
a[2]="cmd_a2"

b[0]="cmd_b0"
b[1]="cmd_b1"
b[2]="cmd_b2"
b[3]="cmd_b3"

case $array in
    a)  tmparr=( "${a[@]}" );;
    b)  tmparr=( "${b[@]}" );;
    *)  printf 'ERROR: invalid array name: %s\n' "$array" >&2
        exit 1;;
esac

for (( i=begin; i<=end; i++ )); do
    cmd=${tmparr[i]}
    printf '%s\n' "$cmd"
done

exit 0
```

- Compared to some alternatives, this has the advantage that it won't do something inappropriate if an invalid array name is provided.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf`.